# Array.from()の中をリセットして更新したい…？？

Tags: javascript, jquery

下記のようなスライダーを自作してみたのですが、`ul.slide_container`を複数設置してしまうと`Array.from()`の`li`の数が２乗づつ増えていってしまいます。

`ul.slide_container`が複数設置されることを想定して、`ul.slide_container`毎に正しく`li`の数が取得できるようにしたいのですが、どうすれば良いのでしょうか…？？

ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

---

```js
addEventListener('load',function(){

  $('.slide_container').each(function() {

    var container = $(this),
        slide_items = Array.from(container.find('li')),
        li_width = container.find('li').width(),
        translate = 0 - (slide_items.length * li_width),
        duration = parseInt(container.css('animation-duration')) * 1000;
 
    function clone_items() {
      for (var i = 0, len = slide_items.length; i < len; i++) {
        $(slide_items[i]).clone(true).appendTo('.slide_container');
      };
    }

    clone_items();

    container.css('transform','translateX('+ translate +'px)');

    loop = setInterval( function(){

      clone_items();

      var li_slice7 = container.find('li').slice(0,slide_items.length);

      li_slice7.remove();

    },duration);

  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slide_container {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: slide infinite linear;
}

.slide_container:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.slide_container li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% { transform: translateX(0px); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container_wrapper">
  <ul class="slide_container" style="animation-duration: 20s; transform: translateX(-2800px);">
    <li style="background-color: red;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: orange;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: yellow;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: green;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: aqua;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: blue;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: purple;"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`appendTo`メソッドは、**引数に指定した値に該当する要素すべての末尾**に、`appendTo`メソッドの前に置かれたコンテンツを挿入します。

質問文のコードでは、`clone_items`関数内の`appendTo`メソッドの引数に対して、`slide_container`クラスを指定しています。この場合、`clone_items`関数を実行する度に、「`slide_container`クラスを持つ**すべての**要素内にある**すべての**`li`要素を足し合わせたもの」をそれぞれの`slide_container`クラスを持つ要素の末尾に追加してゆきます。

すると、次第に`setInterval`メソッド内に記述されている要素の削除が追いつかなくなり、結果として`li`要素の数は増え続けることになります。

これを防ぐためには、**`appendTo`メソッドに各スライダーを識別出来る値を渡せば良い**です。今回の場合は、コードで使用している container 変数を使用出来ます。

```js
addEventListener('load', function() {

  $('.slide_container').each(function() {


    var container = $(this),
      slide_items = Array.from(container.find('li')),
      li_width = container.find('li').width(),
      translate = 0 - (slide_items.length * li_width),
      duration = parseInt(container.css('animation-duration')) * 1000;

    function clone_items() {
      for (var i = 0, len = slide_items.length; i < len; i++) {
        $(slide_items[i]).clone(true).appendTo(container);
      };
    }

    clone_items();

    container.css('transform', 'translateX(' + translate + 'px)');

    loop = setInterval(function() {

      clone_items();
      var li_slice7 = container.find('li').slice(0, slide_items.length);

      li_slice7.remove();

    }, duration);

  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slide_container {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: slide infinite linear;
}

.slide_container:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.slide_container li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container_wrapper">
  <ul class="slide_container" style="animation-duration: 3s; transform: translateX(-2800px);">
    <li style="background-color: red;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: orange;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: yellow;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: green;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: aqua;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: blue;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: purple;"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="slide_container" style="animation-duration: 3s; transform: translateX(-2800px);">
    <li style="background-color: red;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: orange;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: yellow;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: green;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: aqua;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: blue;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: purple;"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="slide_container" style="animation-duration: 3s; transform: translateX(-2800px);">
    <li style="background-color: red;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: orange;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: yellow;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: green;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: aqua;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: blue;"></li>
    <li style="background-color: purple;"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```